# Mum certainly doesn't like it

Tags: riddle, word

> Where a mass lives
>   and which the mass dislikes.
>   When one of the arms eats with a friend.
>   If you do it up, you ruin.
>   I've warned you already, don't do it with me!
>   While in a it, you’re entangled in trouble
>   An icky mash, also a gooey muck.

**What is "it" I am talking about?**

---

See only after you've thought hard:

> Mum certainly doesn't like it, when you make a ____.

Comment: Is the second part necessary to the riddle or is it a hint again? If it's the latter maybe hold off. (Also While in it <- While in a it & An icky <- A icky)

Comment: I would say this is a much better puzzle than the ones You have recently posted. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about

> the word *mess*.

Where a mass lives
and which the mass dislikes.

> According to OP, people live in *messes*.  People as a whole, however, tend to dislike *messes* (the sort that are unclean).

When one of the arms eats with a friend.

> According to a Google search, *mess* (as a verb) can mean to "take one's meals in a particular place or with a particular person, especially in an armed forces' mess."

If you do it up, you ruin.

> If you *mess up*, you might have ruined something.

I've warned you already, don't do it with me!

> Refers to the phrase *don't mess with me*!

While in a it, you’re entangled in trouble

> The phrase *in a mess* can refer to being in a situation full of problems/trouble.

A icky mash, also a gooey muck.

> I had to check this one online, but apparently "mess" is another term for "gooey muck".

And the hint

> Mum certainly doesn't like it, when you make a ____.

refers to the fact that:

> Mothers often don't like when their children make messes.  (This also ties in with the puzzle's title.)

Comment: Correct! +1! You were lightening fast!

Comment: People live in messes. When a member of the military eats with a friend, he messes with that friend.

Comment: I enjoyed it, there were some really clever clues!  I'd agree with n_palum though, the hint made it quite easy to solve (perhaps too easy - I like the subtler version in the title).  I'm still working on that second verse though...

Comment: :-) You're right, except for one part. That arms one. Google `define mess`.

Comment: i was definitely thinking church thoughts... "where a mass lives" sin "what the mass doesn't like... so that makes sense as to why i ran into trouble =p

Answer (score 1):

It is

> a soup !

Where a mass lives
and which the mass dislikes.

> To be provided ...

When one of the arms eats with a friend.

> To be provided ...

If you do it up, you ruin.

> If you make a 'soup' of a work, you may ruin yourself !

I've warned you already, don't do it with me!

> Warning on not to make a soup with the author !

While in a it, you’re entangled in trouble

> If we are in a soup, it reflects that we are in a trouble.

An icky mash, also a gooey muck.

> Cold and other variants of soups are possible ?!

Comment: Creative answer! Like your thoughts! But that's not quite it.